# net domain Command Prompts for a Password?

Tags: shell, bsd

I have a truenas server surrounded by numerous windows boxes.
No domain, the workgroup on all windows boxes is "XYZ".
The workgroup in truenas SMB setup is also "XYZ".

In the truenas GUI console or an SSH console after doing `su -`.

```bash
root@plum[~]# net domain
Password for [XYZ\root]: (Typing a password here produces no characters)
Could not connect to server 127.0.0.1
The username or password was not correct.
Connection failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

I have only one password throughout my entire setup.
All windows boxes, the truenas GUI, SSH login and `su -` all take that same password.

Can someone please help me understand how to deal with this password prompt?